# Why if I run a java project from NetBeans it works but the jar file deosn not work well?

Tags: java, batch-file, exec

my question is: Why if I run a project Java from NetBeans, it works perfectly, but if I create a jar file of the same project, some functions do not work?
Especially, the piece of code below should execute a bat file (in the src folder of the project itself) and move a video from a directory to another.
The java code which does this is:

```
String pathMoveBat = new java.io.File("src\\move.bat").getAbsolutePath();
Process move = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathMoveBat+" "+username+" "+dateFormat.format(currentDate)+" "+i+"");
```

and the file move.bat is

```
cd C:\Users\%1\Videos\LogitechWebcam
FORFILES /M *.wmv /C "cmd /c move @file C:\Users\%1\Desktop\%2\videos\video%3"
```

Comment: Try `cd /d C:\Users\%1\Videos\LogitechWebcam`

Comment: You cant execute bat file from jar. You need to unzip it first.

Answer (score 0):

The process may get started but would almost immediately block unless you care about it's stderr and stdout streams. Check the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html

> By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or
> console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations
> will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed
> via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(),
> getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these
> streams to feed input to and get output from the process. Because some
> native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input
> and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read
> the output stream of the process may cause the process to block, or
> even deadlock.

Another thing is that the src folder usually is not added to the zip, and as others said even if it were you would not be able to access content of it just from the command line.